# Scrape Web Page When Selector Does Not Update URL

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape this webpage (https://nc.211counts.org) for a given region and time ('Onslow', 'Yesterday' for example). I want to pull all of the information from that top left table (COVID, Housing, etc through Other). Unfortunately, the URL does not update when the filters are selected. I have been following the tutorial [here](https://callumgwtaylor.github.io/blog/2018/02/01/using-rselenium-and-docker-to-webscrape-in-r-using-the-who-snake-database/) but cannot find a way to pull in the position of the region names I need to scrape for. Since the `html_nodes` function is returning empty, I think there is something to the mapping that is off.

What am I missing here?

```
# docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome
# docker ps

remDr <- RSelenium::remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost",
                                 port = 4445L,
                                 browserName = "chrome")
remDr$open()

remDr$navigate("https://nc.211counts.org") 
remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE) 
nc211 <- xml2::read_html(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]) 

str(nc211)

body_nodes <- nc211 %>% 
  html_node('body') %>% 
  html_children()

body_nodes

body_nodes %>% 
  html_children()

rank <- nc211 %>% 
  rvest::html_nodes('body') %>% 
  xml2::xml_find_all("//span[contains(@class, 'col-lg-12 chosen-select')]") %>% 
  rvest::html_text()

# this returns empty
nc211 %>%
  rvest::html_nodes("#region") %>%
  rvest::html_children() %>%
  rvest::html_text() 

# guessing at an element number to see what happens
element<- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', "#region > option:nth-child(1)")
element$clickElement()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content is dynamically updated through xhr POST requests when you make your selections and press Search. You can use the network tab to analyse these requests and reproduce them without resorting to selenium (as an alternative). You will need to pick up the param options from the initial page.

[image]

Below I show you how to make a request for a particular zipcode and also how to find out all the zip codes and their corresponding param ids to use in request. The latter needs to come from the initial url.

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)


data = list(
  'id' = '{"ids":["315"]}', # zip 27006 is id 315 seen in value attribute of checkbox node 
  'timeIntervalId' = '18',
  'centerId' = '7',
  'type' = 'Z'
)
#post request that page makes using your filter selections e.g. zip code
r <- httr::POST(url = 'https://nc.211counts.org/dashBoard/barChart',  body = data) 
page <- read_html(r)
categories <- page %>% html_nodes(".categoriesDiv  .toolTipSubCategory, #totalLabel") %>% html_text
colNodes <- page %>% html_nodes(".categoriesDiv .value")
percentages <- colNodes %>% html_attr('data-percentage')
counts <- colNodes %>% html_attr('data-value')

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(categories, percentages, counts)) 
print(df)

#Lookups e.g. zip codes. Taken from initial url
initial_page <- read_html('https://nc.211counts.org/')
ids <- initial_page %>% html_nodes('.zip [value]') %>% html_attr('value')
zips <- initial_page %>% html_nodes('.zip label') %>% html_text() %>% trimws()

print(ids[match('27006', zips)])
```

Comment: This is great. How did you find the id of 315 for the zip code 27006?

Comment: See the end bit of my example. The ids are the _value_ attribute values of the checkbox nodes.

Comment: Any other questions let me know.

Comment: Though early hours here and brain currently shutting down